# Dependency between Application Layer and Domain Layer

Tags: dependency-injection, dependencies, domain-driven-design

I want to reduce the connection between ApplicationLayer and DomainLayer. Consider that I had created an AggregateRoot in Domain Project. It's Ok if I reference Domain directly from Application.
But I want to use the interfaces not the implementation, So I created Domain.Contract that keep the interfaces and contracts of Domain project!Domain has a refrence to this project to implements the interfaces. How can I use this contract in the application layer. in other words:

Domain has the reference of Domain.Contract.
Application Has the reference of Domain.Contract.

In Domain project I have Card Class 
In Domain.Contract Project I have ICard interface
In Application Project I want just reference to the Domain.contract and I have CommandHandlers method that create Card

```
CommandHandlerMethod()
{
   var card = ICard?!!! //What should I do here?
   repository.Save(card);
}
```

One approach that I found is to use a Factory. But factory should now the interface and implemented class, that they are in different project. If I use factory in Domain.contract project it will cause a loop in references. If I use Factory in Domain project how application project will use it?!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Does `ICard` contain any [Volatile behavior](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1) that needs to be abstracted, or is it a mere data contract? Instead of defining an `ICard` in `Contract`, consider moving `Card` itself to `Contract`.

Comment: @Steven thank you for your attention, I want to loose the coupling between Application Layer and the Domain Layer by using Domain Interfaces or just Domain's Factory. In my opinion Application should not know how the domain will build itself.

Interfaces are just mere data contracts in my case.

Comment: Dear @Steven, You can see the dependencies now in my [project](https://github.com/armanleft/MonolithicDDD)'s readme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you can define IFactory interface in 'Domain.Contracts' and leave its implementation in 'Domain'. Now Application layer would know only about 'Domain.Contracts' and the IFactory would be injected in 'ApplicationService' object. In fact the 'Factory' would not be a static class'
Your code should be like this :

```
public class AppService
{
    public IFactory Factory { get; set; }
    public AppService(IFactory factory)
    {
       Factory = factory;
    }
    public void Handle(CreateCommand cmd)
    {
        var card = Factory.Create(cmd.Prop1);
        repo.Add(card);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Mr. Abbasi, You can see the dependencies now in my [project](https://github.com/armanleft/MonolithicDDD)'s readme

Answer (score 1):

Your factory should be implemented in your Domain project and should be fully public.

It purpose is to build an ICard for the application layer, without the application layer need to interact with Card directly.  The constructor on Card can then be internal if deployed in same project as factory.

The Factory should not be in the contract.  The contract should just hold interfaces, not any implementations, including factories.

Yes, the Factory MUST know the interface and implemented class.  That's its job ... to create a concrete implementation of an interface.

References:

- Application > Domain.Contract
- Application > Domain
- Domain > Domain.Contract

**DomainContract**

```
public interface ICard
{
    public string Value { get; }
    public void SetValue(string value);
}
```

**Domain**

```
public class Card : ICard
{
    string Value { get; private set; }

    public void SetValue(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    // INTERNAL.  Can only be created by the factory, not the application
    internal Card(string value)
    {
        SetValue(value);
    }
}

public static class CardFactory
{
    public static ICard CreateCard(string value)
    {
        return new Card(value);
    }
}
```

**Application**

```
ICard card = CardFactory.CreateCard("Ace of Spades");
repo.Add(card);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. The main point of my question was to remove Domain reference from the Application.
I asked question in some groups. One suggested to inject the Factory Interface into the Application classes. Another introduce [Composition Root](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).
I think composition root can solve my problem, just trying to code that, what do you think?

Comment: Yeah, if your aim to make the entire domain model replaceable behind an abstract, then injection of Factory interface would work.  That can work with or without a dedicated microservice / module composition root.

Comment: Dear Neil, You can see the dependencies now in my [project](https://github.com/armanleft/MonolithicDDD)'s readme